# OpenCV Multithreaded Camera Reads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am attempting to use OpenCV to capture images from multiple cameras via separate thread workers.

Eventually, CaptureWorker will feed frames to a worker queue for processing, but currently I'd like to save the image. The following code runs, but the saved 'frames' are damaged and unable to be opened, but are not empty.

Originally, I was constructing and storing the VideoCapture in CaptureWorker::startCapture(); however, the program crashed while opening the stream. Constructing and opening the VideoCapture in main() turns on the camera and allows the thread to run.

What is causing the frame writing to break? No errors are reported.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if(argc <= 1) {
        cout << "No camera arguments have been specified. Exiting." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int numberOfCameras = argc - 1;
    int cameraNumbers[argc-1];

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfCameras; i++) {
        cameraNumbers[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    }

    VideoCapture cameras[10];
    pthread_t cameraThreads[numberOfCameras];

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfCameras; i++) {
        cout << "Creating camera thread: " << i << endl;
        cameras[i] = VideoCapture(i);
        CaptureWorker capWorker(cameras[i], i);
        pthread_create(&cameraThreads[i], NULL, &CaptureWorker::startCaptureWrap, &capWorker);
    }

    cout << "Closing Main" << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

CaptureWorker.cpp

```
class CaptureWorker {

private:
    int cameraNumber;
    string cameraName;
    VideoCapture camera;

public:
    CaptureWorker(VideoCapture camera, int cameraNumber) {
        this->cameraNumber = cameraNumber;
        this->camera = camera;
        this->cameraName = "Camera_";
        cameraName.append(to_string(cameraNumber));
        cout << "CaptureWorker: Worker created" << endl;
    }

    void *startCapture(void) {
        string imageSavePath = "Resources/images/" + this->cameraName;
        mkdir(imageSavePath.c_str(), 0777);

        cout << "CaptureWorker: Starting capture from camera" << endl;
        int count = 0;
        while(count <= 3) {
            cout << "Capturing frame " << count;
            Mat frame;
            this->camera >> frame;
            cout << " --- ";

            string imageNameAndPath;
            imageNameAndPath.append(imageSavePath);
            imageNameAndPath.append("/img_");
            imageNameAndPath.append(to_string(count).c_str());
            imageNameAndPath.append(".jpg");

            cout << "Saving to: " << imageNameAndPath.c_str() << endl;
            imwrite(imageNameAndPath.c_str(), frame);

            int c = cvWaitKey(1000);
            if((char)c==27 ) {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void *startCaptureWrap(void *arg) {
        return ((CaptureWorker *) arg)->startCapture();
    }
};
```

On OSX using cross g++ compiler in eclipse. Disclaimer: New to C++, OpenCV, multithreading, hopefully I've avoided a silly error.

Comment: arent't you waiting for the worker threads to end their processing (in main thread)? before cout << "Closing Main" << endl; there should be a join or sth for each thread...

Comment: From my understanding, the posix pthread_create spawns and joins the thread immediately. When I loops sleeps in main until the threads complete, there is no difference.

Comment: if it joins immediately, how will more threads be created?!? have a look at samples like http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: I was also able to solve the empty image problem by placing my VideoCapture array statically in a shared header.